# How to filter from a mapped entity in java using entity manager

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Below query is not giving correct results when I try to filter in left outer join entity  through entityManager.createQuery in TypedQuery

```
   @Entity
    Class A{
     @Column(name="Duration")  
     private int a;
     @Column(name=ID)
     private int b;

     @OnetoMany
     private List<B> classB;
    }

    @Entity
    Class B{
      @Column(name="Duration")
      private int a;

      @Column(name="country") 
      private String b;

      @ManytoOne
      private A classA;
    }
```

After using create query using TypedQuery:

```
TypedQuery<A> query=entityManager.createQuery("Select distinct ce from A ce join ce.classB cm where ce.ID<5 and cm.Duration<20 and cm.country='US' ")
```

whereClause doesn't work for cm.duration and cm.country. It works for ce.id<5. I don't get any error but my results do not get filtered. Don't know why this is happening.

Comment: What is correct results depends what you want from query. I think you are intentionally doing left outer join not inner join or other type of join. Right? See article https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from

Comment: Yes I am intentionally using left outer join. I want my query to return to me list of Class A entities which contains List<B> -- (having duration and country as specified in where clause)